# MS Access Table Normalization

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 2 excel sheets, in which one sheet contains an organization’s entire employees details with Code, Name, Designation and the other sheet contains the books that an employee had studied. Second table consists of employee code, name and name of the book studied by that employee. One employee might have studied more than one book and one book can be read by many employees.

Now, I want to know how to get a resultant table, which holds employee details from table 1 and appropriate books they have studied from table 2 .

Finally, that table should contain columns of only employee code, name, designation, name of book1, name of book 2. And also in this resultant table I should be able to write queries and export the table contents.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How are you handling the situation where more than one employee has studied a book? the way you have described the data structure is one employee per book. If you want to have many books for many people (many in both directions) you will need to have a joining table that points to both employee and book, and strip out the employeeid from the book reference. But it sounds like the only way to do that in what you have described is to duplicate the book.record.

Comment: You want to import employee data in a separate table, import book data in a separate table and import books read per employee in a separate table, correct?

Answer (score 1):

**That's not Normalization**...

> Database normalization, or simply normalization, is the process of
>   organizing the columns (attributes) and tables (relations) of a
>   relational database to reduce data redundancy and improve data
>   integrity. Normalization is also the process of simplifying the design
>   of a database so that it achieves the **optimal** structure composed of
>   **atomic** elements...
>
> Normalization involves arranging attributes in relations based on
>   dependencies between attributes, ensuring that the dependencies are
>   properly enforced by database integrity constraints. Normalization is
>   accomplished by applying some formal rules either by a process of
>   synthesis or decomposition.
>   <sub>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))</sub>

**That's consolidation** or more commonly referred to as **an Access query with simple joined tables**

Here is SQL for an a sample query which gets data from two joined tables: (based on the fields you named)

```
SELECT EmployeeDataTable.*, BookDataTable.*
FROM EmployeeDataTable 
INNER JOIN BookDataTable 
ON EmployeeDataTable .ID = BookDataTable.ID;
```

Queries don't get much simpler than that.

---

Is this a one-time merging of data or will you need to continually import data from Excel?  That might change the steps slightly, but either way it sounds like you'll need to find some beginner's tutorials for Access.  (There are plenty on YouTube that are great for beginners.)

Before anything, you'll need to **get the data into Access**.  Simple and self-explanatory if, in your Access database, you click the `External Data` tab and then `New Data Source` then `From File` and `Excel`.